# when getting output of system() calls in ruby only part of output is getting stored

Tags: ruby

when am running some deployment command in ruby script like

```
system('exam-deploy-all mod.rb >> temp.txt')
```

only part of output is getting stored in `temp.txt` file. I want to store whole output, I think its not storing because the output is very big. 
Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're losing output because there is too much, I'd guess that some of your output is going to the standard output stream (which you are saving in `temp.txt`) and some is going to the standard error (which you are not saving anywhere). You could try this:

```
system('exam-deploy-all mod.rb > temp.txt 2>errors.txt')
```

To put the output in `temp.txt` and the errors in `errors.txt` or one of these:

```
system('exam-deploy-all mod.rb > temp.txt 2>1')
system('exam-deploy-all mod.rb &> temp.txt')
```

to put them both in `temp.txt`.

Also, doing `>> temp.txt` appends the standard output to `temp.txt` without overwriting what is already there, `> temp.txt` will overwrite `temp.txt` with the new output.

All of this assumes that you're using something unixish (such as Linux or OSX) and that you system shell is Bourne-ish (such as bash).

You could also switch to [Open3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/classes/Open3.html) if you want to handle all the I/O yourself rather than relying on [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001441) and temporary files. Using Open3 is more work but it may be worth it or maybe it isn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend... Its working, I was spending my time on this since 3 hrs. Thank you very much...:)